# Invalid Host header

Tags: javascript, post, get, postman

When i try to make `GET`or`POST` it response me with `Invalid Host header`

Can someone tell me where is the problem?

P.S im using **POSTMAN** for testing this rests 
[image]

Comment: Provide all the info regarding your request. All the header data, etc

Comment: Your question is a bit broad. Please take the time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do we have a clear view now @AlbertoTrindadeTavares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and use Postman Interceptor to get around this.

> Chrome apps, by default, cannot send certain headers (Host is one of
>   them) in XHR requests.

https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/interceptor_extension

[image]